# Django from Submit button doesn't do anything

Tags: python, django, forms, django-forms

I'm new to Django, and I'm trying to submit a form to process the data in a view function, but I can't find why when I press the Send button it doesn't do anything. i read many other questions but were syntax related problems, which I believe is not my case.

Here's my form. It is in the new.html template:

```
<from action="{% url 'notes:create' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type='text' name='note_name' id='note_name' placeholder='Title...'>
    <input type='date' name='note_date' id='note_date'> 
    <input type="submit" value="Send"> 
</form>
```

Here it is urls.py:

```
app_name = 'notes'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    path('new/', views.new_note, name='new'),
    path('output/', views.create_note, name='create')
]
```

And here the views.py file. Currently the create_note view only redirects to the index. I'm going to process the entered data once the form works correctly.

```
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'notes/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'all_notes'

def get_queryset(self):
    return Note.objects.all()

def new_note(request):
    return render(request, 'notes/new.html')

def create_note(request):
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('notes:index'))
```

Comment: You have a typo in your form html element <from should be <form

Comment: I can't believe I made such mistake. Thanks a lot!